# Display TEXT on Right side corner

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap CSS. On my header page, all the page links display, in the same link I want to display the **LOGIN USER NAME RIGHT SIDE CORNER.**

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Link1</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Link2</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Link3</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Logout</a></li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Hi @Context.Session.GetString("UserName")</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approch will help you.

- Add `flex-grow-1` class to `ul` this will make your `ul` element to grow to full width of parent.
- Add `ml-auto` tp the required `li` element. This will add a `margin-left: auto` to that element will will take maximum space at left. This will push your element to right most end.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Link1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Link2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Link3</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-dark">Logout</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item ml-auto ">
      <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Hi Admin</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>
```